# Wavepropagation through air - EMC test values 100V/m

Tags: waves, radiation

I am reading the Automotive International standards ISO 11452 and it states that I must have a chamber in which I must generate 100V/m on a range of frequency.

[image]

**My question is:** In which circumstances around the world do I get in the air over 100V/m?

For example the GSM in Europe is between 880-915MHz and I am curious when is my driving car "bombarded" with electromagnetic energy with over 100V/m over that frequency range?

Comment: Did you mean *Wave propagation*?

Comment: I just wanted to understand the request of generating Test Level  IV -  100V/m on the freq range of 200-1000MHz, because I had many requests like that when I worked as an EMC Test Engineer, even 200V/m. But I think I understand now, hypothetically if I have a carrier with 896 MHz using an transducer ( antenna ) with 18 dBi, I can send a EM wave over 2 km , having at destination an E-field of 1V/m using 7.4 kW at the transducer ( antenna ) input. If something is closer to the TX antenna when transmitting that wave, let's say at 20 meters, the E-field will be ~100V/m, right?

Answer (score 2):

Field strength in the far field is $E = 5.477 \frac{\sqrt{P}}{r}$. If P is watts and r is meters, then E is V/m.

So 100 V/m is approximately the field strength of

- 100 W at half a meter
- 1000 W at 1.7 meters
- 10 kW at 5.5 meters

etc. as long as the frequency is high enough to make those distances significantly more than a wavelength. If that's not true, you're in the near-field, and so the electric field strength could be higher (or, then again, it could be lower, depending on the radiator and the exact distance).

Comment: It was in my understanding that every mobile phones has an IMEI which is the modulation frequency applied on the signal carrier that comes from a network relay. For example: I used a E-field probe RadiSense 10 ( Dare Instruments ) and measured a 1-5V/m carrier signal outside an EMC chamber while I was using my phone. Let's say that I have a network antenna at 1000 meters away from my phone and for the signal to be 1V/m at 1000m it needs around 33kW of power. If my calculations are right, at 10 meters away from the relay network at 33kW the E-field is 100V/m, right?

Comment: If I am looking closely at your formula, you are using a Monopole Antenna in which the gain is 1 and basically if we use a directional Antenna with greater Antenna Factor / Isotropic Gain we can drastically reduce the power needed for the same distance of 1000m , right?

Comment: @i33SoDA An IMEI is not a frequency. And your scenario is nonsense because you're forgetting about the phone itself. No one uses anything close to 33kW, but 1W at a few cm is a different story. And yes, I forgot to write it, but I'm talking about EIRP, not any particular antenna.

Comment: My scenario was ask based on your formula for using Monopoles Antennas. I know that the communication is done between two carrier towers with your phone being in the "way" of the EM wave carrier TX - Phone (Burst) - RX.  Sorry to be such persistent, I understand that IMEI is an identification number which a carrier can identify. But, this means it has to "modulate" the carrier with a unique signature in order to recognize it. There are even sites in which you can insert your IMEI number to check if the phone frequencies is supported by the carrier. Maybe I should use EIR instead of modulation?

Comment: To simplify my question about IMEI:  If IMEI is an unique identifier number of a cellphone that a carrier can identify, because that carrier transmits a carrier signal it means that my phone in order to transmit my signature it needs to... modulate/encrypt the carrier frequency, RIGHT?

Comment: @i33SoDA no, 100% of that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The test severity level is something that will be requested, or specified, between the purchaser and the supplier. In other words you don't just "comply to ISO 11452", you will have a requirement for conducted and radiated susceptibility to be at severity level 3 for some frequency band, and 2 for others, etc. I can't quickly find out what would typically be expected or required by national law etc, but it's probably not the maximum.

A normal cellular phone will generate more than 30 V/m near the device.

If you were around for the arrival of phones in the 1990s, you'll remember all the electromagnetic compatibility issues then. Radios and alarm clocks buzzing. My PDA would be scrambled by a phone near it. I discovered that my phone would unlock the office door keycard system from the outside. In an underground parking lot, my 50 watt ham radio would reliably trigger the alarms in parked cars. And in an EMC chamber once I found a "one arm bandit" slot machine being tested, they obviously have very good reasons to want to be immune to RF interference.

These issues have largely been solved now, driven by these improved standards, so you don't hear the buzz in audio devices, and you don't expect computers and gadgets to be scrambled by your phone. You're allowed to use your phone on an aeroplane.

Back to the vehicle: handheld radios, up to 8 watts, could generate nearly 100 V/m near the radio. Worse, a vehicle-mounted 80 watt transceiver, with its RF connection partially undone so only the centre pin makes contact, would generate much more, right under the dashboard. Consider that these tests are for safety systems like the airbags, not just the audio amplifiers, and 100 V/m sounds like a reasonable level.

As a quick calculation: for a TEM (far field) wave, $ P_d = {E^2\over{377}}$ so 100 V/m is a power density of 26 watts per square metre. 80 watts would achieve 100 V/m inside a sphere of about 1 metre diameter.

The field strength from the cellphone towers and other external sources will be much, much smaller, less than 1 V/m.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer, I am born in 91. It was in my understanding that all mobile phones have an IMEI which is the modulation frequency applied on the carrier which comes from a relay network. My question is: If the carrier signal that reach my phone is 5V/m ( I measured it with an Laser Powered Probe – RadiSense 10 "Dare Instruments" ) from a relay that it is 4 km away, what is the E-field for the same energy that arrives at my phone but measured at let's say half the distance?

Comment: Maybe you have a strong local transmitters, usually FM radio? The probe really needs to be used in a shielded room. Or you need to zero the probe. 5 V/m is quite large for a home or office environment. A 30 W base station 1 km away will produce a field strength of about 0.2 V/m. And IMEI is just like your phone's MAC address or its email address, nothing to do with the field strength.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of power density, a signal traveling with a field strength of $E_0$ V/m will have an average power density of
$$\left<S_i\right> = \frac{E_0^2}{2\eta_0}$$
where $\eta_0$ is the characteristic impedance of free space:
$$\eta_0 = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}} \approx 376.73\Omega$$

---

At Test Level IV
$$\left<S_i\right> = \frac{100^2 \text{V}^2/\text{m}^2}{2\cdot376.73\Omega} \approx 13.3 \text{W}/\text{m}^2 
$$

Is this a realistic ambient power level?

The output power density due to a radiator with $P_T$ watts input to an antenna with gain $G$ as a function of range, $r$, will be in free space:
$$\left<S_i\right> = G \frac{P_T}{4\pi r^2}$$

The legal maximum output power of a WiFi transmitter at 5 GHz is 4 W.  WiFi antennas typically have antenna gains in the range of 2-4 dBi (dB over an isotropic equivalent). Plugging 2 in for $G$ ($\approx 3$ dBi) and 4 in for $P_T$ we get:
$$\frac{2\cdot4\text{W}}{4\pi r^2} = 13.3 \text{W}/\text{m}^2 \rightarrow r=\sqrt{\frac{8}{4\pi\cdot 13.3}}\text{m} \approx 0.05 \text{m or } 5\text{ cm}$$

So a scenario here might be an internal WiFi hotspot in a car to deliver internet to passengers that could be close to some automotive component.  So the scenarios aren't completely unrealistic.

---

<sup>General formula for field strength at a given distance from an emitter (free space model):
$$
\frac{E_0^2}{2\eta_0} = G \frac{P_T}{4\pi r^2} \rightarrow E_0 = \sqrt{2\eta_0\cdot G \frac{P_T}{4\pi r^2}}
=
\frac{1}{r}\sqrt{\frac{\eta_0GP_T}{2\pi}}
$$</sup>